# TFVCGet@2 is failing consistently but on different files

Tags: azure, azure-devops, tfs, azure-devops-extensions

I have an ADO build pipeline where we need to download files from a TFVC source. We are using the task TFVCGet@2. This has been working for months now without any issues but since yesterday it has been failing while trying to download files. It fails consistently but for random files.

```
##[error]Request timeout: /******/_apis/tfvc/items?path=%AZP2524%AZP252FLHI-Projects%AZP252F*****%AZP252FDevExpress.Printing.v15.1.Core.dll
##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.issue type=error;]Request timeout: /****/_apis/tfvc/items?path=%AZP2524%AZP252FLHI-Projects%AZP252F*****%AZP252FDevExpress.Printing.v15.1.Core.dll
##[error]Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'F:\A\B1\externals\node10\bin\node.exe', arguments '"F:\A\B1\_work\_tasks\TFVCGet_25bd5165-40a2-4ea9-80d6-e47b9ee4550e\2.2.4/TFVCGet.js"'.
##[debug]Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessExitCodeException: Exit code 1 returned from process: file name 'F:\A\B1\externals\node10\bin\node.exe', arguments '"F:\A\B1\_work\_tasks\TFVCGet_25bd5165-40a2-4ea9-80d6-e47b9ee4550e\2.2.4/TFVCGet.js"'.
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Util.ProcessInvoker.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.ProcessInvokerWrapper.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, InputQueue`1 redirectStandardIn, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, Boolean keepStandardInOpen, Boolean highPriorityProcess, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.DefaultStepHost.ExecuteAsync(String workingDirectory, String fileName, String arguments, IDictionary`2 environment, Boolean requireExitCodeZero, Encoding outputEncoding, Boolean killProcessOnCancel, Boolean inheritConsoleHandler, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.Handlers.NodeHandler.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.TaskRunner.RunAsync()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Agent.Worker.StepsRunner.RunStepAsync(IStep step, CancellationToken jobCancellationToken)
```